# WebStorm file suddenly loses color coding and icon turns gray

Tags: webstorm

During the last day I've encountered a behaviour on WebStorm where a JS file suddenly loses color coding and it's icon becomes gray with an "X".

[image: gray icon]

no color coding:

[image: color coding]

Any idea why?

Comment: Seems like you have marked that file as "Plain text". Right click on it in Project View panel and look for "Mark as JavaScript" .. or maybe even  "Unmark as Plain Text" option.

Comment: yes, I wonder how I managed to do that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on file icon ... it seems that you have used "Mark as Plain Text" action on it.

[image]

To undo -- do the opposite: right click on that file in Project View panel and choose `Mark as JavaScript` item.

[image]